# What is the weight of diamond dust?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, treasure, spell-components, weight

I am in a game where the DM likes us to track the weight of everything. I even have every single coin tracked. As a cleric I am going to be carrying around diamond dust for some spells, but I cant find a listed weight anywhere. The weight for coins and gems are listed, but not for this.

Does anything have a suitable weight and hopefully a source for it?

Comment: Have you tried asking your GM?

Comment: 1 gram of diamond dust weighs 1 gram

Comment: Then what is the value of 1 gram of diamond dust

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 1 gram / 50 gp of diamond dust, or 1 lb / 22680 gp of diamond dust

While this uses 3.5e for the calculation it seems likely to hold in pathfinder.

- [Reddit user Sarlax noted that the 3.5e Nondetection spell is the only one to use both a cost, and volume, of diamond dust](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/2frvl8/56_lbs_diamond_dust/ckcayfy/) giving us a starting point that a pinch of diamond dust is worth 50gp.
- [A pinch is 1/16 of a teaspoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_(cooking)) (for cooking purposes anyway but cooking is a kind of a magic so it'll do)
- [So 50gp of diamond dust is 1.081 grams](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((1%20teaspoon%20in%20cm%5E3)%20%2F%2016)%20*%20density%20of%20diamond)

Compared to coins this is a modestly efficient way of transporting gold value.

Comment: Only *modestly* efficient? Are you going to make me pose a question to get a more efficient currency than 22,680 gp per lb.?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Considering this is 3.5e/Pathfinder I thought I'd hedge my bets. Optimization is a hell of a drug.

Comment: Until you posted this, I assumed the highest money-to-weight item, at 1,040 gp per lb., was saffron (*AE* 31). But you're absolutely right to hedge; there's *probably* something better. I mean, gems and souls are weightless, right?

Comment: Gems are not weightless, they have the same weight as coins, that is 50 to a pound, at least in pathfinder

Comment: @Fering I am always interested in this kind of trivia. Can you cite a source for the weight of gems? I found a 2011 thread saying [gems are widely considered to have negligible weight](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n0wn?PFS-converting-GP-to-Gems-is-there-a-cost#16) in Society play, but I got nothin' otherwise.

Comment: I have looked trying to find why I would have thought this, and the only thing I can determine is that the weight of the gems is a house rule to give them the same weight as coins.